# Exception not giving the file or line it occurred on

Tags: c#, .net

Exception:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffe
r& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo in
fo)
   at Plus.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Not giving me a line or file, this could be in any of the 3,000 files in my solution.

Exception happens in here, apparently but that could lead to anywhere. I do have build debugging on full and I can't find anything about this on other questions that'll work.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        DatabaseManager = new DatabaseManager(_configuration);
        LanguageManager = new LanguageManager();
        SettingsManager = new SettingsManager();
        FigureManager = new FigureDataManager();

        new ServerStatusUpdater();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a debug build. Put a breakpoint in the catch block and look at `e.StackTrace` in the watch window.

Comment: It happened in `Plus.Program.Main`.  What don't you understand?

Comment: @SLaks If that Main() method in his question is Plus.Program.Main, what he doesn't understand is where it's calling ParseInt32(). On the other hand, maybe what he doesn't understand is which Main() he pasted into the question.

Comment: @SLaks It's impossible to have that exception type when all you're doing it initiating classes. Your comment is wrong, it clearly happened somewhere higher up the call stack than Program.Main. That's the problem I am having here, it's not telling me where it happened. The exception was caught in Program.Main, doesn't mean it occurred there.

Comment: @chaotic: That's not how stack traces work.  Unless you're writing `throw ex;` (which you should never do), that should not happen.

Comment: You can also go to Exception Settings in VS and have it break on System.FormatException

Comment: @SLaks It's physically impossible for it to throw a FormatException in Main, the code isn't there to cause it, I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: Unless you're seeing some wack inlining, stack traces don't work like that either.  Nothing will remove frames from the middle of a stack trace.  Can you post a standalone repro?

Comment: If you have troubles with modern debugging, `Console.WriteLine` is always your friend. Narrow down the part of code which throws the exception (and get rid of the universal `catch`).

Comment: Like others commented above, merely using the reported information to locate the cause is far from reliable (release build, inlined functions and so on matter a lot). If you do have a way to reproduce it, use a debugger (VS, or WinDbg) to analyze the exception then.